# Use BroadcastReceiver that asks a user if they wish to open app onReceive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

I am trying to create an app that communicates with USB flash drive. I would like to have the user prompted and asked if they wish to open the app once the intent "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" is received.

Currently, I have the onRecieve() set up so that it launches the main activity

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent startIntent = context
            .getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());

    startIntent.setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
    );
    context.startActivity(startIntent);
}
```

I would like to have the user prompted for permission first, a good example of what I would like to achieve is ES File Explorer [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6fAV.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to have the user prompted and asked if they wish to open the app once the intent "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" is received.

The screen you want to show has to from your app so in fact is has already started, even if the user perceives it differently.

What you can do is start an activity when this broadcast is received (you need to be in activity context to be able to show stuff on the screen). Make the activity's background transparent and have it show a dialog on top that handles the user's input. From there you either start the next activity, or not.

Comment: ahh yes okay. So in the ES file explorer example, they've created an activity to look like a dialog box, asking the user if they want to launch the main activity?

Comment: I don't know how they did it, but you cannot show a dialog unless the app is already running, and has an active component that can show dialogs (activity or fragment)

Comment: Do you mean running as in the app has already been opened at some point prior?

Comment: if the app has not been opened by the user before, it will not be able to do anything at all. But let's assume the user has opened it before - when the broadcast receiver fires and your app is handling it, your app is "running". I mean to say the user can think he is deciding whether or not to start the app, but in fact it is already running otherwise it could not handle the broadcast

Comment: Thanks for your help.